# Making App default handler on OSX 10.10 with sandbox enabled

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I wasn't able to find anything online about this, but LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme will return -54 when the sandbox is enabled. I'm not sure what entitlement needs to be turned on for this to work as it does without the sandbox on.

To see this in effect, create a new project with this in the appdelegate:

```
-(void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Become default handler
    CFStringRef bundleID = (CFStringRef)CFBridgingRetain([[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]);
    OSStatus result = LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme(CFSTR("maxel"), bundleID);
    if (result != 0) {
        assert(0);
    }
}
```

It will work. Next turn on sandbox. It will fail with -54 in result.

Built on OSX 10.10 Yosemite. Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Apple's developer forums, you can't do this anymore in the sandbox--the behavior you are seeing is expected. It's really aggravating, because no alternative API exists to implement this functionality, short of stepping outside of the sandbox.

Comment: That is.. it really kills one of my app's features :( I was hoping to at least find a temporary exception for this but it doesn't look like anything is listed: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH5-SW1

Comment: Okay so from searching on the dev forums it seems like in 10.10 Apple wants Launch Services to figure out default apps on its own. I ended up using http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/ to manage them